# Making kubectl apply command idempotent in ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I want to provision a cluster via successive resource application within a cluster.

At some point in time, I want to apply an `nginx` deployment, the one suited for the creation of `nginx` - based [ingresses](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#prerequisite-generic-deployment-command), so I want to run the following command in a shell:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.27.0/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
```

My question is how can I make this idempotent, i.e. not to fail when the resources exist.

Is the `k8s` `ansible` [module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) suited for this?

Comment: Unless you are not doing much with Kubernetes insides your Ansible tasks, the module would indeed be much better for your uses. Since it requires the `openshift` Python module dependency, the cost-benefit is better if you plan on doing more with Ansible and Kubernetes in conjunction.

Answer (score 3):

`kubectl apply` won't throw an error if the resource already exists. It is suited for your need. `kubectl create` will throw error if resource exists.

Answer (score 1):

@Shashank V is right in his answer but I would like to expand it a bit with a help from the official documentations.

[Apply](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#apply) manages applications through files defining Kubernetes resources. It **creates and updates** resources in a cluster through running `kubectl apply`. This is the recommended way of managing Kubernetes applications on production. See [Kubectl Book](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/app_management/apply.html).

Definition, usage and flags can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply):

> Apply a configuration to a resource by filename or stdin. The resource
>   name must be specified. This resource will be created if it doesn't
>   exist yet. To use `apply`, always create the resource initially with
>   either `apply` or `create --save-config`.

I hope it makes the topic clearer.